# Finding duplicate number in couple SQL Server tables in c#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server database with a couple tables with records. My input is IMEI number that I must store in a table only if this IMEI number is not saved in all tables. my code is:

```
public int Find_IMEI(string IMEI_NUM) 
{
        IMEI_lab.Text = IMEI_NUM.ToString();
        int dflag = 0;
        object result;

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=manager_db;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        sqlConn.Open();
        int test = 0;

        for(int kk = 0; kk < comboBox2.Items.Count; kk++)
        {
            string data_sql = string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM {0} WHERE IMEI={1}) SELECT 1 AS FOUND ELSE SELECT 0 AS FOUND", data[kk], IMEI_NUM); 
            SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand(data_sql, sqlConn);
            result = da.ExecuteScalar(); // ExecuteScalar fails on null

            if (result.GetType() == typeof(DBNull)) // checking IMEI number in all Tables(orders)
            {
                dflag = 0;
                test = test + dflag;
            }
            else
            {
                dflag = (int)result; //(Int32)da.ExecuteScalar();
                test = test + dflag;
            }
        }

        sqlConn.Close();
        return test;
    }
```

This code is working fine, returns count of found duplicate IMEI numbers in all tables. But I want to know if SQL has query that do the job in more optimize way or without loops

Table definition :

```
id |  IMEI       | Serial   | date
----------------------------------------
 1   3548690...    0001       15/2/15
 2   3548690...    0002       15/2/15
```

P.S data[kk] - array with tables names

Comment: Table definitions please! And with sample data and wanted result it's even better!

Comment: tagged mysql but you are working wirh SqlConnection then this should be Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the single request to SQL server instead *N* requests, where *N* is the number of your tables, using the `UNION` clause.

You need some like this request:

```
SELECT SUM(C) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM {Table1} WHERE IMEI = @IMEI
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM {Table2} WHERE IMEI = @IMEI
    UNION
    . . .
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM {TableN} WHERE IMEI = @IMEI
)
```

As far as I understand, your `data[]` array stores the names of tables.

```
var tableRequests = data.Select(tableName => string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM [{0}] WHERE IMEI = @IMEI", tableName));
var innerRequest = string.Join(" UNION ", tableRequests);
var finalRequest = string.Format("SELECT SUM(C) FROM ({0})", innerRequest);
using (var command = new SqlCommmand(finalRequest, sqlConn))
{
    commman.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", IMEI_NUM);
    return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, the right code with syntax will be:var tableRequests = data.Select(tableName => string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM {0} WHERE (IMEI = {1})", tableName, IMEI_NUM));
            var innerRequest = string.Join(" UNION ", tableRequests);
            var finalRequest = string.Format("SELECT SUM(C) AS EXP FROM ({0}) AS ANS", innerRequest);
            
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(finalRequest, sqlConn))
            {
                return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }

Comment: hi, can u help again with query string for retrieving datarow of found IMEI value in all tables?

Comment: @Arbo Hi. Table requests are `"SELECT * FROM [{0}]"`, where `{0}` is a table name. `UNION` remains `UNION`. The final request is `"SELECT * FROM ({0}) WHERE IMEI={1}"`, where `{0}` is `innerReqeust`, and `{1}` is desired IMEI value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableRequests = data.Select(tableName => string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM {0} WHERE (IMEI = {1})", tableName, IMEI_NUM));
var innerRequest = string.Join(" UNION ", tableRequests);
var finalRequest = string.Format("SELECT SUM(C) AS EXP FROM ({0}) AS ANS", innerRequest);

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(finalRequest, sqlConn))
        {
            return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

thanks to @Mark Shevchenko